# How do you use "all()" in a conditional in python?

Tags: python, syntax

For example, if A were a list of ints, and I wanted to say "if every element of A is equal to 3, then...etc"

```
if all(A) == 3:
    #then do this
```

Not quite sure of the syntax or how to express it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if all(a == 3 for a in A):
    pass
```

For testing that all items in a collection are identical, another fun option is to use a `set`:

```
if set(A) == {3}:
    pass
```